# Camera led flash wont work on one Android device

Tags: android, flashlight

I implemented a function to toggle the flash light, but it turns out that one device has a weird behavior: Alcatel POP S3 One Touch.

I tried the same code on other devices like

- Samsung Note 3 (OFW (rooted) 4.4.2) -> flawless
- Samsung Galaxy S2 (OWF 4.2.2) -> flawless
- Samsung Galaxy S2 (Cyanogenmod 4.2.2) -> some delay when turning on/off
- Alcatel POP S3 x5050 (OFW 4.3):

  As Release: Sometimes nothing, sometimes a short flash

  While debugging: Sometimes it magically works, sometimes nothing, sometimes short LED flash...

Is there something wrong with my code?

```
//classmember:
//Camera camera = null;
public Boolean toggleLight() {
    // check if camera is present and has flash support
    Boolean hasFlash = context.getApplicationContext().getPackageManager()
            .hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_FLASH);

    if (hasFlash) {
        if (camera == null) {
            try {
                // create camere instance (only when facing_back camera is
                // present)
                camera = Camera.open();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG, e.getLocalizedMessage());
                return false;
            }
        }
        // get camera infos
        Parameters params = camera.getParameters();
        // get flash status as string
        String isFlashOn = params.getFlashMode();
        if (isFlashOn.equals(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF)) {
            // only gets here if flash is "off"
            params = camera.getParameters();
            // turn on the flash light
            params.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
            // LED should turn on here
            camera.setParameters(params);
            // should help on some devices, but not important(?)
            camera.startPreview();
            return true;
        } else {
            // all other cases would release the camera to make it available
            // in a second try
            params.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
            // turn flash off
            camera.setParameters(params);
            // stop preview if started
            camera.stopPreview();
            // release the camera resources
            camera.release();
            camera = null;
            return false;
        }
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}`
```

Comment: may or may not be your code. You could try another phone (same model) and see if it's an error with the phone/emulator?

Comment: I'll try tomorrow, when I get the second devices back. But after this I'm running out of devices^^ Is it possible to test flash light in Android emulators?

Comment: I honestly don't know. I saw this though? http://viralpatel.net/blogs/enable-camera-in-android-emulator/ so there *might* be a possibility? (BTW, I've only used devextreme/win8 phone dev, so not exactly a genius here on mobile apps)

Comment: So I testet on another Alcatel Pop S3 and here it's most likely the same. It does work a bit more often, if you press the "toggle light" button often enogh, though. Some collegues gave me their devices like LG Optimus X2 P990 and HTC Sensation, but it's working just fine.